# BreakIterator doesn't find correct sentence boundary with parenthesized "i.e." or "e.g."

Tags: java, breakiterator

In the example below, `BreakIterator` appears to be failing on a fairly straightforward example.

Am I using `BreakIterator` incorrectly, or is this just a bug?

Example class:

```java
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.Locale;
public class BreakIteratorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String text = "Due to a problem (e.g., software bug), the server is down.";
        BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US);
        bi.setText(text);
        int r = bi.preceding(30);
        System.out.println("bi.preceding(30) returned " + r);
        String sentence = r == BreakIterator.DONE ? text : text.substring(0, r);
        System.out.println("first sentence: \"" + sentence + "\"");
    }
}
```

Output:

```sh
$ javac BreakIteratorTest.java 
$ java BreakIteratorTest
bi.preceding(30) returned 21
first sentence: "Due to a problem (e.g"
```

It seems like `bi.preceding(30)` should have returned `BreakIterator.DONE` instead.

JDK version 1.8.0.

Comment: Which part of the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) made you believe that it supports abbreviation periods? You can't claim it's a bug, if it never said it is supported.

Comment: @Andreas: that was my first thought, but it literally says "Sentence boundary analysis allows selection with correct interpretation of periods within numbers and abbreviations".

Comment: I could reproduce the behaviour with OpenJDK 16 and also realized that only `preceding` seems to be affected. Forward-searching for sentence boundaries seems to skip the `e.g.` as expected. And last but not least: `preceding(30)` **does** skip the nonsensical construct `.g.e` (i.e. it skips dots on the "wrong" side of abbreviations).

Comment: JDK bug created here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8264765

Comment: I'd add a comment to the bug that it only seems to happen for `preceding` and forward-searching works correctly. But I don't have an account on that bug tracker and am too lazy to do create one ;-)

Comment: I don't have an account either. They don't let little people like us have accounts on the bug tracker.